# おいでいただけませか grammar

Tags: grammar, honorifics

A humble way of requesting others to do something is: (verb in て-form)+ていただけませか.

おいで is short for おいでなさい. It is the honorific お + いでる, which is an Ichidan verb, so the て-form is おいでて.

Should it be おいで**て**いただけませか instead of おいでいただけませか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct phrase is:

> おいでいただけませ**ん**か？
>
> Would you please come?
> (super-literally: "Can't I receive a favor of your coming?")

- It's ませんか, not ませか. ません is the negative form of ます (you can see why in the super-literal translation above).
- おいで is indeed from お + [いでる](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%87%BA%E3%81%A7%E3%82%8B), but you need the masu-stem, not the te-form here. Please remember the [basic rule](https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=20356). Just like you say お掛けいただけませんか ("Would you please have a seat?") and お話しいただけませんか ("Would you please talk about it?"), you need to say おいでいただけませんか. Note that いでる is a dated verb that is no longer actively used outside a few fixed expressions such as おいでになる, おいでなさい, おいで and いでよ.